# Sharing a track with polylines on facebook from my android app

Tags: android, facebook, google-maps-android-api-2

I am tracking the user location with polylines in my android app. When the user finishes tracking his route i would like to let him share the route in Facebook and in Whatsapp.

I don´t want to take a screenshot of my app interface and share it, I want to share the google map with the user`s tracking.

I've been looking for the answer everywhere but I haven´t found any question related to this point.

I am using Google Maps v2.

Thank you everyone for your answer.

Comment: you can use Google Static Maps api, idk if thats good for you but you download the map as a bitmap and you would have to redraw the route on the map

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: Thank you very much JRowan. I'm having a look at it and it seems very interesting. I will try this. Again, thank you :)

Comment: your welcome, hope it works out :)